# Finding a jumbled character sequence in minimum steps

Tags: javascript, cryptography, backtracking

There is a string consisting of all alphabets(a-z). I have to guess the jumbled sequence in minimum number of steps. After each guess, I will know if each of my character is in the right position or not.

I'm using the following approach:

1. Maintaining a list of indices of where each character can go

   Generating a random sequence from above and updating the list on each response

Here's my code:

```
var validIDs = {};

function initialise() {
  let indices = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25];
  for(let i=0;i<26;i++) {
    validIDs[String.fromCharCode(97+i)] = [...indices];
  }
}

// response is a bool array[26] 
// indicating the matching positions of pattern with the secret jumbled sequence.
function updateIDs(pattern, response) {
  let index;
  for(let i=0;i<pattern.length;i++) {
    if(response[i]) {
      validIDs[pattern[i]] = [i];
    } else {
      index = validIDs[pattern[i]].indexOf(i);
      validIDs[pattern[i]].splice(index,1);
    }
  }
}
```

My `validIDs` is an object with `[a-z]` as keys and stores the possible positions of each character. Example: `{ a: [0, 1, 2], b: [3], ...and so on till 'z' }`. The aim is to tighten the constraints on this object and finally arrive at the secret pattern.

I'm trying to create a valid pattern from this object without using brute force and would like to have some randomness as well. I wrote the following function to take a random index for each letter and create a sequence, but this fails if all the available indices of a letter are already taken.

```
function generateNewSequence() {
  let sequence = [], result = [];
  let rand, index = 0;

  for(let letter of Object.keys(validIDs)) {

    //Finding a random index for letter which is not already used
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*validIDs[letter].length);
    while(sequence.indexOf(validIDs[letter][rand]) !== -1) rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*validIDs[letter].length);

    index = validIDs[letter][rand];
    sequence.push(index);
    result[index] = letter;
  }

  return result.join('');
}
```

Note: Another constraint is that the generated sequence should not contain any duplicates.

Comment: I think it is exceedingly hard to understand what your code is supposed to do. Maybe you could give an example of the input / expected output. Some comments would be nice as well. If you're analyzing you're generally try to reduce randomness, not introduce it.

Comment: Are you asking for an efficient algorithm to brute force all options for the first character, then effectively remove the first character from consideration when brute-forcing the second character, and so on?  If so, then there are some very simple algorithms based on keeping a list of the characters you haven't found a home for yet, and scanning the list at each position, removing an item once it is found to be the correct item for a given position.

Comment: I've refactored the above code a bit. Yes, brute forcing is one way to find a valid pattern, but is there something more efficient using some data structures, like a trie or something similar.